# How to move character string in ncurses screen?

Tags: python, ncurses

For example, I have a character string "Hello world" at the first line.
How can I move it to the second line？

ps: I know I can use code like this:

```
import curses

stdscr = initscr()
stdscr.adstr(x,y,"Hello World")
y += 1
stdscr.erase()
stdscr.adstr(x,y,"Hello World")
stdscr.getch()
```

but I have lots of context under this "Hello World", I'd like to find a way which will move or erase "Hello World" only. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text takes only one line you can use the [`clrtoeol`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.clrtoeol) function to erase the whole line starting from the cursor:

```
curses.setsyx(y, 0)   # beginning of the correct line
# stdscr.move(y, 0)   # alternative
stdscr.clrtoeol()    # clears the current line
```

Alternatively you can use the [`hline`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.hline) function to insert a whole line of whitespace:

```
stdscr.hline(y, 0, ord(' '), 80)   # where 80 is the width of the screen
```

Comment: when I use curses.setyx， it returns that module has no attribute setyx

Comment: @Mario Ops. Typo. It's [`setsyx`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.setsyx) with the `s`. Or you can use the [`move`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.move) method of the window objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`curses.panel.Panel.move`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.panel.html#curses.panel.Panel.move):

```
import curses
import curses.panel

x = 3
y = 3
stdscr = curses.initscr()


w = curses.newwin(1, 20, y, x)
p = curses.panel.new_panel(w)
w.addstr(0, 0, "Hello World")
w.getch()

p.move(y+1, x)
curses.panel.update_panels()
curses.doupdate()
w.getch()

curses.endwin()
```

BTW, parameter to `addstr` is `y, x, str`, not `x, y, str`.

See [Demo](http://asciinema.org/a/7491)